# react+redux: state of store changed without view changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I try to use `react-redux`. Use `connect` as in tutorial. I have 2 modules with `export default connect(...)(...)`. When dispatched in one module dev-tools show changing and new state, but view of another module don't changed.

App.js

```
const App = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <UserForm />
            <FlexGrid>
                {props.testStore.persons.map((data, index) =>
                    <PersonCard data={data} key={index} /> // <!-- This not changed
                )}
            </FlexGrid>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        testStore: state
    }),
    dispatch => ({})
)(App);
```

UserForm.js

```
const UserForm = (props) => {
    let nameInput, familyInput, patronymicInput;

    const addUser = () => {
        props.addUser({
            name: nameInput.value,
            family: familyInput.value,
            patronymic: patronymicInput.value
        });
    }

    return (...);
}

export default connect(
    state => ({
        testStore: state
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        addUser: (data) => {
            dispatch({ type: 'ADD_USER', data});
        }
    })
)(UserForm);
```

How fix it?

Comment: Show your reducer, it's looks like you are mutating state.

Comment: function storeChangeHandler(state = stateInit, change) {
 if (change.type === 'ADD_USER') {
  state.persons = [...state.persons, change.data];
 }

 return state;
}

Comment: Ya you are mutating state

Comment: Is it bad? after dispatching dev-tools show correct state of store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mutating your state in reducer. You need to keep your state immutate like this

```
function storeChangeHandler(state = stateInit, change) { 
  if (change.type === 'ADD_USER') {
    return{
       ...state,
       persons: [...state.persons, change.data]
    };
  } 
  return state;
}
```